# How to check the machine type? laptop or desktop?

Tags: c#, wmi

How to check current machine type? laptop or desktop ?

I got this from http://blog.csdn.net/antimatterworld/archive/2007/11/11/1878710.aspx ,it works well on my home machine(Win2003 on laptop), it returns "Portable", but failed on my work machine(Vista on laptop), it returns "Other".

here is the code:

```
public enum ChassisTypes
{
    Other = 1,
    Unknown,
    Desktop,
    LowProfileDesktop,
    PizzaBox,
    MiniTower,
    Tower,
    Portable,
    Laptop,
    Notebook,
    Handheld,
    DockingStation,
    AllInOne,
    SubNotebook,
    SpaceSaving,
    LunchBox,
    MainSystemChassis,
    ExpansionChassis,
    SubChassis,
    BusExpansionChassis,
    PeripheralChassis,
    StorageChassis,
    RackMountChassis,
    SealedCasePC
}

public static ChassisTypes GetCurrentChassisType()
{
    ManagementClass systemEnclosures = new ManagementClass("Win32_SystemEnclosure");
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in systemEnclosures.GetInstances())
    {
        foreach (int i in (UInt16[  ])(obj["ChassisTypes"]))
        {
             if (i > 0 && i < 25)
            {
                return (ChassisTypes)i;
            }
        }
    }
    return ChassisTypes.Unknown;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you just trying to determine whether the machine is likely to be used outside of the office?

Comment: i'm with John Saunders: what are you trying to achieve? There is a reliable way to check if the machine is running on a battery - is that what you're hoping to find out by asking laptop or not?

Comment: There is no reliable metric to determine what form factor a system is; moreover, you have no way to determine what future form factors might possibly 'look' like a current Laptop device given any specific metrics. The real question here is why on earth is the form factor of the system your code is running on important?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

read registry key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\pcmcia, the ‘Start’ value, it's laptop if start =0, otherwise it's desktop machine if start doesn't exist or start != 0.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 Professional on VAIO VPCCW2DGX/B and the start value is  3 !! this answer is not accurate.

Comment: What if my laptop doesn't have PCMCIA? Or my slim-line desktop does?

Comment: My desktop system has a PCMCIA PCI card - does that make it a Laptop?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I may be attempting to raise the dead here, but I would suggest that the most reliable method of determining a laptop would be the present of a lid status switch. 
See [GetPwrCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and [System_power_Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps not the best, but surely a very good hint to test on your fleet.... avoiding the WMI mess. thanks you

Comment: Best answer for avoiding WMI.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a good Microsoft article that suggests looking at a few other WMI classes to get a better idea of whether the computer is a laptop or desktop:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180825.aspx

```
Win32_SystemEnclosure, ChassisTypes(1)=10
Win32_Battery or Win32_PortableBattery
Win32_PCMCIAController
Win32_DriverVXD.Name = "pccard"
Win32_ComputerSystem.Manufacturer
Win32_ComputerSystem.Model
```

And it also suggests to look in the registry for the Power scheme.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for both **Other** and **Unknown** check.

Change the condition to  `i > 1  && i < 25` and remember `ChassisTypes` is an array where OS returns what ever he thinks your system is.

It is possible to match more than single type. Your code only returns the first match.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that this will depend on whether the manufacturer has bothered to provide that data on the current chipset.  If they have not, then "Other" is the best you can do.

[Check out this somewhat related article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081218-00/?p=19783), which also suggests [querying the BIOS directly](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/tools/article.php/c12347#Sample).

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/sept04/hey0921.mspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387204(VS.85).aspx which states that:

> This documentation is derived from the CIM class descriptions published by the DMTF.

Presumably, that means the manufacturer had to provide some information for Windows to be able to discover it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a definitive right answer for this and I've found WMI unreliable for it but I have been using the Win32 function GetSystemPowerStatus() to determine if there is a system battery, obviously system battery == portable computer.

I've never tried this on a desktop with a UPS though?!

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if machine is laptop or desktop you can try to check battery status, using SystemPowerCapabilites.LidPresent or both of them.

Battery:

```
if(SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus ==BatteryChargeStatus.NoSystemBattery){
  //desktop 
}
else{
  //laptop
}
```

SystemPowerCapabilites.LidPresent:

```
public SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES getSystemPowerCapabilites(){
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES systemPowerCapabilites;
    GetPwrCapabilities(out systemPowerCapabilites);
    return systemPowerCapabilites;
}

getSystemPowerCapabilites().LidPresent;
```

GetPwrCapabilities definition: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/powrprof/GetPwrCapabilities.html