# .NET - how to identify machine type (laptop/desktop) and screen type (crt/lcd)

Tags: c#, .net, screen

Is there a foolproof way for a .NET app to identify...

- whether a machine is a laptop or a desktop
- whether the screen is an LCD or a CRT
- the size of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope if this works for you

[How to check the machine type? laptop or desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384642(VS.85).aspx)