# How can I know if the computer is desktop or laptop? by c# code

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check the machine type? laptop or desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop)

How do I know if the computer is desktop or laptop? by c# code

Comment: chaeck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop). You may be able to find some useful information there.

Comment: There is some wrong information floating around on the related answer pointed out by Hansmukh, so I'm not voting to close this just yet. Are you interested in knowing if the computer is capable of running on *battery* power, or if it's actually a desktop vs portable?

Comment: I want to know - desktop or laptop

Comment: Then your best bet is [Bing's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop/1013515#1013515) in the duplicate question, which suggests querying several different WMI classes and comparing the results to those expected for a portable computer.

Answer (score 5):

Check the battery status!

Comment: I want to know the machine type - desktop or laptop

Comment: Desktops don't have batteries

Comment: What about those hooked up to UPS'?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. What is the difference exactly? 
Best guess is to think of components that only appear in laptops, battery, mobile CPUs etc.

Why do you want to know that btw? Some UI logic because of it?

Also remind Virtual Machines can run on either.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryChargeStatus == BatteryChargeStatus.NoSystemBattery)
 {
    //Desktop
 }
 else
 {
      //Laptop
 }
```

Comment: -1 Incorrect. The battery is currently out of my laptop, and this code indicates it is a desktop.

Comment: This is a pragmatic answer and could be improved with some text explaining its limitations.  So whilst this code doesn't handle the battery being removed from a laptop or a UPS (reported as a battery) connected to a desktop it may cover most use cases and be a valuable stop gap.  Based on @RvDK answer its worth recommending a redesign so the application doesn't depend on what type of device its running on just its capabilities.

Comment: If you combine it with recognizing the mousepad of the laptop, I think calling it a laptop is safe enough.