# How can I check if the computer is desktop or mobile

Tags: c#, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check the machine type? laptop or desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop)

How can I check if the computer is desktop or mobile,
in WIN7 - 
read registry key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\pcmcia, the ‘Start’ value, the value in laptop is not =0, value = 3, Also the value in desktop =3. 
This way there is no way of knowing the type of the computer

Comment: I agree - WMI is good alternative to using registry when solving problem above

Comment: how do I use with WMI? do you have an example for me?

Comment: why closed? The answer there is not good

Comment: It was closed because this question was already asked.

Answer (score 0):

If possible avoid direct access to registry. You may try:

```
System.OperatingSystem osVersion = System.Environment.OSVersion;
// ...
PlatformID yourPlatform = osVersion.Platform;
// ...
```

Comment: I get "win32NT", not desktop or mobile

Comment: I see - Sorry my bad - I thought you wanted to compare 'mobile device' and 'PC' but it was desktop and notebook. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop looks fine.