# using C++ on Mac, how to check if the machine is a laptop or desktop?

Tags: c++, macos

On PC, there's a way to do as this post suggests [How to check the machine type? laptop or desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013354/how-to-check-the-machine-type-laptop-or-desktop)

I need to do the same on a Mac. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example is C#, not C++. This would not be a feature in standard C++. It might be possible with CoreFoundation.

Comment: Why is it important? A laptop user could run your program remotely on a server or desktop, and vice-versa!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm doing statistics on users who are running our software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to get machine model:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

size_t len = 0;
sysctlbyname("hw.model", NULL, &len, NULL, 0);

char* model = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
memset(model, 0, len + 1);

sysctlbyname("hw.model", model, &len, NULL, 0);
printf("%s", model);
free(model)
```

which on my MBP prints "MacBookPro5,5". Other models include "MacBookAir", "iMac", "Macmini", "MacPro". So, if there is "book" in the model name then it's likely a laptop:

```
if (strcasestr("book", model)) {
    // This is laptop
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrey. That's a very quick answer.